# rand() keeps giving me the same number and decreasing 4 by variable

Tags: c, random

I was trying to do this work for a class i have but for some reason i can't get the `rand()` to work, i've tested several diferent things to try and get it to work, but i just can't figure it out. I'm new to C so i might be doing something wrong here please help.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand( time(NULL) );
    int num, rep, nu, ba, bas;
    char B[20] = "";
    char C[20] = "";


    printf("Jogo: Converter Bases!\n");
    printf("\n Quantas perguntas desejas responder? (1-6)");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while (num <= 0 || num > 6) {
        printf("\n Introduz um  valor valido de 1 a 6: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }
    for (int p=0; p<num; p++) {
        nu=rand()% 10;
        bas=rand()% 3;
        ba=rand()% 3;

        printf("\nnu = %i bas = %i ba = %i", &nu, &bas, &ba);

        while (ba = bas) {
            ba = rand()% 3;
        }
        if (bas = 0) {
            char B[20] = "Octal";
        } else if (bas =1) {
            char B[20] = "Decimal";
        } else {
            char B[20] = "Hexadecimal";
        }
        if (ba = 0) {
            char C[20] = "Octal";
        } else if (ba =1) {
            char C[20] = "Decimal";
        } else {
            char C[20] = "Hexadecimal";
        }
        printf("Converte %i de base %c para base %c\n", &nu, &B, &C);
        scanf("%d", &rep);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: Please be a bit more specific on your input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: [`printf()`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man3/printf.3.html) takes values not pointers. (Except when you actually want to print  a memory address.) So you should say, for example, `printf ("...", nu, bas, ba)` and not `printf ("...", &nu, &bas, &ba)`. And so on. Essentially you are not printing what you think you are printing.

Comment: How can you tell that *"rand() keeps giving the same number"*?

Comment: @AlexP That is probably an answer :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.  For example, those `if`/`else` chains that do nothing but declare and initialise variables `B` and `C` (shadowing `main()`'s `B` and `C`, and never used) should be omitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're writing:

```
printf("%d", &x);
```

When you should be writing

```
printf("%d", x);
```

In the first case you're printing the **memory address** of the variable; in the second - the contents of the variable.

The `&` is required for `scanf`, because it needs to know the memory address where to put the results, but printf only needs the value.

Comment: This is probably a sign that insufficient warnings are enabled.  Compilers provide plenty of warnings, and experienced C programmers enable as many as they can!